# How to apply merge to a branch without being on it?

Tags: git

I want to do merge to my branch with the master when I on another branch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVgOL.png)

I did this:

```
$ git fetch origin dev/FW-5116_hw_monitor_multi_platform:tst/QA-1641_voltage_monitor
```

and I get thus message:

```
fatal: refusing to fetch into branch 'refs/heads/tst/QA-1641_voltage_monitor' checked out at 'C:/workspace/OM/lidar-fw'
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: The easiest thing you can do right now is create a new worktree and run the merge there. `git worktree add blahblah some-branch; cd blahblah; git merge something-else; cd ..; git worktree remove blahblah`

Comment: Your error message seems to be a separate issue from the question in your title - it's saying that fetching data from the remote server has failed.

Comment: Thanks, bat I work in an organized place, it's not normal to do that, isn't there a simpler way in essence?

Comment: why?(fetching data from the remote server has failed)

Comment: You cannot fetch into the currently checked out branch. You must choose between `git pull` (with possible merge) and `git pull --rebase`.

Answer (score 0):

You have, in effect, asked two separate questions:

**Q: How can I merge into a branch without being on the branch?**
The answer to this question is simply "you can't"—at least, not with Git versions up through the current one 2.38.1).  Currently, merge *always* operates on the current branch.  There are some specialized things, including what you're trying to do, that *aren't* `git merge`.

**Q: What does the error message here mean?**

> ```
> fatal: refusing to fetch into branch
> 'refs/heads/tst/QA-1641_voltage_monitor' checked
> out at 'C:/workspace/OM/lidar-fw'
> ```

This refers to your attempt to use a specialized non-merge `git fetch` operation:

> ```
> git fetch origin dev/FW-5116_hw_monitor_multi_platform:tst/QA-1641_voltage_monitor
> ```

in *combination with* `git worktree add`.  That is, you've previous used `git worktree add` to create a local checkout of branch name `tst/QA-1641_voltage_monitor` in the directory `C:/workspace/OM/lidar-fw`.  Git knows—or at least believes—that this local checkout still exists.

You have several options for fixing this second problem:

- remove the added working tree, e.g., using `git worktree remove` (make sure you save any unsaved work before removing it!);
- if the added working tree is *already* removed, inform Git to this effect using `git worktree prune`, assuming that the added working tree is not also locked (see [the `git worktree` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree));
- using the added working tree, run your fetch-and-merge operation *there*.

For instance, using the bash shell, you could run:

```
pushd /C/workspace/OM/lidar-fw
git fetch
git merge origin/dev/FW-5116_hw_monitor_multi_platform
<finish the merge if necessary>
popd
```

Or, lacking bash and `pushd`/`popd`, you could open a separate window with whatever shell you prefer, and change your working directory to `C:/workspace/OM/lidar-fw` (which is probably how I'd do this in the first place).